# How to delete an unlisted version of an google app engine service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google App Engine. When checking the output logs from my service, I correctly see the logs of the version(s) I expect to see. However, additionally, I also see logs of a very old version that is running alongside those versions. Its ID is shown in the browser console, at the start of the lines it outputs.

The problem is that this old version's ID does not show up anywhere in the Versions tab. When attempting to delete/stop it via the command line the following message shows up "WARNING: No matching versions found", and it keeps on pushing to our logs.

Any advice on how to stop/delete this version? It seems quite sketchy to have code running on a version that is not listed anywhere.